# Text to Speech in browser - Get voice like Siri/Google

Tags: html, web, text-to-speech

I am developing a web app which will need to convert given text(1000+ chars) into speech. I was going to use Google translate but that has the limit of 100 chars.

I have tried HTML5 SpeechSynthesis but it has a weird male voice (I guess it's using OS' voice). So basically I need a voice like Siri or Google (OK Google type). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: SpeechSynthesis has many voices you can choose from

Comment: Siri or OK Google voices are "embedded" in the OS - on a windows machine i don't think you can find them. But yes as @Phiter mentioned from this API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/voice you can set a voice.

Comment: Another service from Google is https://cloud.google.com/speech/

Comment: @DrNio I know that speech synthesis has many voices but all these voices are either of OS or a few of browser. I tried all of their voices and they sound robotic to me. That's why I thought voice of Sir will be a good option. And the other link you provided is for speech to text, not the other way around.

Comment: I couldn't assume that you know that the API has many voices :)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has a great service that allows yo to convert text into voice with many different voices and accents and works in different languages as well.

> Amazon Polly is a service that turns text into lifelike speech, allowing you to create applications that talk, and build entirely new categories of speech-enabled products. Amazon Polly is a text-to-speech service that uses advanced deep learning technologies to synthesize speech that sounds like a human voice.

[Amazon Polly](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/)

**Update**
Amazon gives you 5 million characters per month for free for the first year of use, after that is a paid service

Comment: "Low Cost

Amazon Polly’s pay-as-you-go pricing, low cost per character converted, and unlimited replays make it a cost-effective way to enable speech synthesis in virtually any application."

Comment: Thanks Luis for the info! I didn't know that service. Also google has something similar https://cloud.google.com/speech/